# GCP DLP unable to run dlp.deidentify_content method get exception The request concerns location 'us-east1' but was sent to location 'global'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I am calling the method dlp.deidentify_content in the following code. The KeyRing is made in region us-east1 and the keys are generated using HSM. GCP did not allow to generate a HSM key for a global key ring.

```
 # Import the client library
import google.cloud.dlp

# Instantiate a client
dlp = google.cloud.dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient()

# Convert the project id into a full resource id.
parent = dlp.project_path(project)

# The wrapped key is base64-encoded, but the library expects a binary
# string, so decode it here.
import base64

wrapped_key = base64.b64decode(wrapped_key)

# Construct FPE configuration dictionary
crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config = {
    "crypto_key": {
        "kms_wrapped": {
            "wrapped_key": wrapped_key,
            "crypto_key_name": key_name,
        }
    },
    "common_alphabet": alphabet,
}

# Add surrogate type
if surrogate_type:
    crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config["surrogate_info_type"] = {
        "name": surrogate_type
    }

# Construct inspect configuration dictionary
inspect_config = {
    "info_types": [{"name": info_type} for info_type in info_types]
}

# Construct deidentify configuration dictionary
deidentify_config = {
    "info_type_transformations": {
        "transformations": [
            {
                "primitive_transformation": {
                    "crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config": crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

# Convert string to item
item = {"value": string}

# Call the API
response = dlp.deidentify_content(
    parent,
    inspect_config=inspect_config,
    deidentify_config=deidentify_config,
    item=item,
    #location_id="us-east1",
)

# Print results
print(response.item.value)
```

When I run the code I get the error,

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Received the following error message from Cloud KMS when unwrapping KmsWrappedCryptoKey "projects/PROJ_NAME/locations/us-east1/keyRings/dlp-test3/cryptoKeys/key7": The request concerns location 'us-east1' but was sent to location 'global'. Read go/storky-stubby for more information.

I am unable to figure out how to send the request from a specific region. Ideally I would want to have the key-ring as global. However, GCP does not allow HSM keys for global key rings and as a result cannot have a wrapped_key for that key.

Can someone suggest how to overcome the error?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud HSM keys cannot be created or imported in some locations, such as [global](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key#create_targets), this is only possible with [Cloud EKM keys](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/locations#multi_regional). If you want to use Cloud HSM in an available location such as “us-east1” you can follow these steps for [importing keys to a region](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key).